# Autopopulate form input texboxes with javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, auto-populate

I have this following problem because I don't have expertise in Javascript

I'm testing a Facebook login at
http://goo.gl/3R3owa

After the user is logged in Facebook an alert windows with the birthday and location comes up. So far so good.

Rather than show that window i will like to autopopulate the day, month and year input boxes in that page.

Is there any way to do that?

Here is my code
http://goo.gl/IFhJdu

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have all the data in the `response` object and `element_id#` is a valid id of an element present on the HTML page. You can simply use following JS code do set the value of an input field in JS:

```
document.getElementById('element_id1').value = response.gender;
document.getElementById('element_id2').value = response.birthday;
document.getElementById('element_id3').value = response.location.name;
```

Similarly, for feeding the data to an HTML element, you can use `innerHTML`, for example:

```
document.getElementById('element_id1').innerHTML= response.gender;
```

(You can use the above code to replace the `alert()` method in you JS code.)